# Appeare Angular Compile Error: Failed to find 'node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css'

Tags: css, json, angular, fonts, font-awesome

'm facing a compile-time error. The font-awesome folder is present in node modules, but still on compiling I get compile-time error. My angular.json looks like this:
{
"$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
"version": 1,
"newProjectRoot": "projects",
"projects": {
"grocery": {
"projectType": "application",
"schematics": {},
"root": "",
"sourceRoot": "src",
"prefix": "app",
"architect": {
"build": {
"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
"options": {
"outputPath": "dist/grocery",
"index": "src/index.html",
"main": "src/main.ts",
"polyfills": [
"zone.js"
],
"tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
"assets": [
"src/favicon.ico",
"src/assets"
],
"styles": [
"src/styles.css",
"node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
"node_module/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
],
"scripts": []
},
"configurations": {
"production": {
"budgets": [
{
"type": "initial",
"maximumWarning": "500kb",
"maximumError": "1mb"
},
{
"type": "anyComponentStyle",
"maximumWarning": "2kb",
"maximumError": "4kb"
}
],
"outputHashing": "all"
},
"development": {
"buildOptimizer": false,
"optimization": false,
"vendorChunk": true,
"extractLicenses": false,
"sourceMap": true,
"namedChunks": true
}
},
"defaultConfiguration": "production"
},
"serve": {
"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
"configurations": {
"production": {
"browserTarget": "grocery:build:production"
},
"development": {
"browserTarget": "grocery:build:development"
}
},
"defaultConfiguration": "development"
},
"extract-i18n": {
"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
"options": {
"browserTarget": "grocery:build"
}
},
"test": {
"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
"options": {
"polyfills": [
"zone.js",
"zone.js/testing"
],
"tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
"assets": [
"src/favicon.ico",
"src/assets"
],
"styles": [
"src/styles.css",
"node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
"node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"

```
        ],
        "scripts": []
      }
    }
  }
}
```

}
}

Comment: please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.